# I am getting "ACCESS_DENIED" error when I tried to create the "put_bucket_replication" using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

**I am trying to run the py script which has replication_configuration, while executing I am getting "ACCESS_DENIED" error.**

**Rrplication_configuration.py**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.put_bucket_replication(
    Bucket='s3remotestaebackendbucket',
    ReplicationConfiguration={
        'Role': 'arn:aws:iam:::role/tf-iam-role-replication',
        'Rules': [
            {
                "ID": "abcd",
                'Prefix': '',
                'Status': 'Enabled',
                'Destination': {
                    'Bucket': 'arn:aws:s3:::s3remotestaebackendreplicationbucket',
                    'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'
                }
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

**Error**

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketReplication operation: Access Denied**

**S3 ROLE**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**POLICY**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${var.source_bucket_arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${var.source_bucket_arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${var.destination_bucket_arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**IAM_USER_PASSROLE**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam:::role/tf-iam-role-replication"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can any one help me to fix this error. Where I had done the mistake?
This sample code will include the terrraform variable declarations